# Edit a file using grub

Tags: file, edit, boot, grub

I did a really bad mistake in the rc.local boot file. I added a process with an infinte loop to the list in this file so that my arch linux distro is not able to boot completly because this process blocks the further boot procedure.

Is there a way to edit this rc.local file in grub so that I can remove this process?

Answer (score 7):

Grub doesn't come with a text editor that I know of.

Your best solution here would probably be to boot using a liveCD for another distro (the Arch install media can do that), mount the drive upon which your file resides, and edit the file there. Then unmount and reboot normally.

Answer (score 1):

try do it
https://www.maketecheasier.com/reset-root-password-linux/
in root mode you can also edit file

Comment: thanks, editing the command line was my rescue!